# How to parse JSON in apex from lightning component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, json

Following is the JSON structure. 
[image: This is the JSON structure]

**I want to deserialize this data structure in APEX to Update the Records**, sobject is dynamic not every time 'Contact', I am confused how deserialize this data structure to Update the record
Just for more info here is the Js function.

```
   addRelatedRecord:function(cmp,evt,help){
    let arrofRecs = [],Ids = cmp.get('v.selectedIds'),objName = cmp.get('v.objectName'),
    relatedApiName = cmp.get('v.RelatedListFieldAPI'),recID = cmp.get('v.recordId');
    Ids.map(val =>{
        let obj = {};
        obj['SobjectType'] = objName;
        obj[relatedApiName] = recID;
        obj['Id'] = val;
        arrofRecs.push(obj);
    })
    console.log(arrofRecs)
    //------------------------------------
    let methodName = 'c.updateRecord',
        params = {
            'json':JSON.stringify(arrofRecs)
        },
        callbackRess = (response) => {
            if (response) {
                let data = JSON.parse(response)[0];
                cmp.set('v.NonRelateddata',data);
                console.log('data', data);
            }
        }
    console.log(params)
    help.callApexMethod(cmp, methodName, params, callbackRess);
}
```

Comment: What could be other `SObjectType` here? You can pass this information along with in your apex method and utilize switch/if-else to de-serialize the JSON based on that information.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy. Just pass attributes as list of maps, and in Apex just do

```
(List<Contact>) JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(records), List<Contact>.class)
```

or

```
(List<SObject>) JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(records), List<SObject>.class)
```

The method signature would be the following.

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void method(List<Map<String, Object>> records) {
```

Comment: getting error :Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void serialize(List<Map<String,Object>>) from the type List<Map<String,Object>>

Comment: You missed `JSON` name of the class, you shouldn't call `serialize(records)` but `JSON.serialize(records)`

Comment: Here is the method i am try to using.... 
`@AuraEnabled
    public static string updateRecord(List<Map<String, Object>> json){
        System.debug('json'+json);
      List<SObject> lst = (List<SObject>) JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(json), List<SObject>.class);
      System.debug('lst'+lst);
        return 'Done';
    }`

Comment: rename `json` to `records` or to something else, don't use standard class names like `JSON`, `Test` etc as the name for variable or class.

Comment: Sarvesh kumar, please avoid extended discussions, either update your post with the problem or create a new one